# Droppable and Draggable in TABLE TD

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="drag" style="height: 80px; width: 30px; background-color: red"></div>
<div class="drag" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: green"></div>
<div class="drag" style="height: 120px; width: 30px; background-color: blue"></div>

<table id="droppable" border="1">
    <tr> <td>a1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr> <td>a2</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr> <td>a3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr> <td>a4</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

$(function() {
    $( ".drag" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable td" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
});​
```

Please get the first div - green and drop **start** on TD **a1**. console.log show `<td class=​"ui-droppable">​a1​</td>​`. This is ok.

Please get the second div - red and drop **start** on TD **a1**. console.log show `<td class=​"ui-droppable">​a2​</td>​` This is bad. Should be `<td class=​"ui-droppable">​a1</td>​`

And please get the third div - blue and drop **start** on TD  **a1**;console.log show 
`<td class=​"ui-droppable">​a3​</td>​` This is bad. Should be `<td class=​"ui-droppable">​a1</td>​`

How i must doing that show me **a1** always if i drop **start** on **a1**?

http://jsfiddle.net/RuC8t/1/

Comment: Should be http://jsfiddle.net/RuC8t/2/ right? I can't edit it because SO thinks the edit is too minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made 2 changes:

In the HTML I replaced the content of the div ('start') with this:

```
<span class="dragHandle" style="position: fixed">start</span>
```

In the JS I replaced your

```
$( ".drag" ).draggable();
```

with this:

```
    $( ".dragHandle" ).draggable({
        drag: function ( event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().offset({ top: ui.offset.top, left: ui.offset.left});
        }
    });
```

This way it's only the handle at the top that being dropped (and not the center of the tall DIV) and we still move your colorful DIVs :-)